# Angular-translate is not working in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I have a problem in Angular JS, 
I wanna translate my web site into english
So, to do that, i'm using translation module as following:
in my **app.js**, i did this:

```
    var app = angular.module("user",["ui.router","pascalprecht.translate"]);
    app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {
    .....
    },
    function( $translateProvider )

{

     $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('null');
     $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'frZZZ'], {
         'en_*': 'en',
         'fr_*': 'fr'
          })
          $translateprovider.fallbacklanguage('en');

    $translateProvider.translation("en", {
        compose_dishes: 'COMPOSE YOUR DISHES ACCORDING TO YOUR DESIRES',
        adapt_foods: 'Adapt Foods and Quantities'
    });
    $translateProvider.translation("fr", {
        compose_dishes: 'COMPOSEZ VOS PLATS SELON VOS ENVIES',
        adapt_foods: 'Maîtrisez les Aliments et les Quantités'
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
})
```

now i wanna use it in my controller which is in an other js file ( home.js ),
here i have injected my $translate composent:

```
    ///////le controller home/////
    var app = angular.module("user");


    app.controller( "homeCtrl", function($scope,$http,$state,$rootScope, $compile, $translate, $filter ) {
.....
}
```

and in my view i'm trying to translate "compose_dishes" word that is declared in app.js and put it in a `h1` tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700|Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="user" ng-controller="homeCtrl"  id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">



<!-- Intro Section -->
<section id="intro" class="intro-section">
......

<h1 translate="compose_dishes"></h1>

......

</section>
```

but the result is like this image:

[click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4mCW.jpg)

it's just showing the equivalent key to the word, and when i put any thing which is not defined, it is showing it also, that means that the controller doesn't know the existence of the defined key in app.js .

**please help me :'(** .

Comment: Can you please provide a small plunkr or fiddle for your case ?

Comment: Here's the documentation of Module.config(): https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config? Does it say that it takes two functions as argument?

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the language to use ? `translate.use('fr');`

Comment: @JBNizet is on the right track. You are passing two functions as arguments to `config()` but it should only be one. Try `app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {
    .....
    }`

Comment: thank you @JulienTASSIN, this is jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/MohammedESSABRI/sfnt8d6z/

Comment: thanks @JBNizet i will see that

Comment: @JBNizet it is done but it shows me **$translateProvider.translation is not a function** on this line :

`$translateProvider.translation("en", {
  compose_dishes: 'COMPOSE YOUR DISHES ACCORDING TO YOUR DESIRES',
     adapt_foods: 'Adapt Foods and Quantities'
 });
 $translateProvider.translation("fr", {
  compose_dishes: 'COMPOSEZ VOS PLATS SELON VOS ENVIES',
     adapt_foods: 'Maîtrisez les Aliments et les Quantités'
 });`

Comment: @JBNizet
note that i have already some lines which contains $translateProvider above those are : 
`$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('null');
 $translateProvider.registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'fr'], {
   'en_*': 'en',
   'fr_*': 'fr'
    })`

thank you very much

Comment: There is indeed no method named `translation` in $translateProvider. Once again, everything is simpler if you read the api documentation: https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translateProvider

Comment: hello @JBNizet
thank the problem is solved ! 
i have just an other problem, is with french special characters like ' é ' wich i put in the json file that is used by angular-translate
it's appearing like this /?\ ( that means uknowen carachter )
can you give me a solution ?
thank you very much